# Is the common saying that sitting close to a screen regularly can cause short-sightednes backed by medical science?

Tags: eye, ophthalmology, myopia-nearsightedness

How true is this? Should I be cautious as I spend too much time in front of a laptop screen? I already have glasses with power 0.5 and 0.25, ( this was 3 years ago, I haven't tested recently) but I very rarely use it because I feel I'm less human that I have to use glasses, that I have poor eyesight and its psychologically unsettling for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly an association between reading at short distances and myopia. Here's an article that suggests a possible mechanism:  [Reading and Myopia: Contrast Polarity Matters](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-28904-x) Basically, they suggest that reading surfaces which are mostly light (like white paper or screen background) with dark text overstimulate certain retinal pathways and may stimulate the eye to grow longer front to back, leading to myopic misfocusing. They note that natural non-reading scenes provide more balanced stimulation of retinal pathways, which might explain the association of reading with myopia.

The authors also note that reading text with a dark background and light letters (what we would call "dark mode") seems to cause much less overstimulation and so might be something practical to try.